# Hide few fields in EditForm.asx of Picture Library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a picture library and added few fields to it. When i click add new item from picture library, the EditForm.aspx appears after uploading the picture. This form contains many fields of which I want to hide Title, Date Picture Taken, Description, and Keyword. In short the EditForm should contain only Name, Preview and the columns that I have added. Is it possible to hide the other columns? I want to perform this out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possibilities.

- You can use SharePoint Designer to manipulate the NewForm, EditForm and DisplayForm. Edit the existing form, use CSS to set the out of the box HTML form to hidden, then add a new custom form to the page and remove the columns you don't want to see.
- If you don't want to use these columns at all, just delete them in the Library settings
- If you don't want to delete the columns, click the parent content type in the Library settings, then edit each column and set it to "hidden"

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2009/10/hide-column-in-edit-new-or-display-mode.html

I found this solution to be really simple and effective. Very well documented and descriptive.